# Custom flagging a question asks me if I want to migrate

Tags: bug, custom-flags, flag-dialog

This seems to be an intermittent bug. Custom flagging a post asks me if I want to migrate the question. Clicking flag again closes the dialog and the flag seems to be raised after second click.

> Think this question should be migrated to another site? Please first check that it is clearly-written and on-topic for the site you're recommending. If you aren't an experienced member of that site, please take some time to read their help center first; rejected migrations are frustrating to both askers and the good people on the site who must reject it. Thanks!

The API `add/PostOther` fails the first time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Potentially because you have the word "move"? Sounds like the sort of broad stroke detection that would be in place.

Comment: @Nick that is weird since there is vote to migrate.. (Not sure how it used to be for lower rep)

Comment: Custom flags have been used to ask mods to migrate/move questions to another site. This is why there is a simple check for some words

Comment: @Dharman so I need to change the phrase "move to chat" or drop it entirely... Weird thing to trip over.

Comment: Yes, it's triggering the warning on "moved". Lots of people raise flags saying, "this question should be moved to site x". If you're saying "moved to chat", simply ignore the warning. It should not cause the POST to *fail*, though. If that's happening, that's a bug.

Comment: @CodyGray as the second image shows "success" is false. So the message shows up and flag dialog remains as is. Second click on flag question is successful. I assume from what you all are saying, this is intended behaviour if you want the user to recheck to migrate...